# Problemas com \ no update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Tenho um campo de uma tabela que guarda o caminho para um arquivo armazenado localmente. Quando executo o seguinte comando:

```
UPDATE tabela1 set caminho = 'c:\logs\caminho.txt' where cod_tab = 1
```

ele grava sem a barra invertida. Portanto, ele guarda da seguinte forma:

c:logscaminho.txt

Alguem tem uma sugestão do que pode estar acontecendo? O caminho é digitado entre aspas simples (string).

Obs: MYSQL (PHPMYADMIN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é porque tem de fazer o escape do `\`, quando quiser inserir 'backslashes'. Faça:

```
UPDATE tabela1 set caminho = 'c:\\logs\\caminho.txt' where cod_tab = 1
```